# Languages word list and dictionary formats

Tags: dictionary, tinymce, spell-checking

In my current application i am using a tinymce plugin called nanospell, this plugin come with many different dictionaries but it is missing one that is very important for my application (French Canadian), do you guys know where i could find a French Canadian dictionary/word list that i could include in the nanospell dictionaries. It would also help to just find any French Canadian file with a list of words and try to reverse engineer the file to make it work with the format nanospell uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/word-finder-francais/ they seem to have a similar word list